# Is It Possible to Derive an Attribute from other Tables Attribute

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

Is it possible to derive the attribute "total cost" from "Total Cash Purchases" and "Total Salary Paid".
Im also open for suggestion if there are any problems in my diagram. Thanks

[image]

Comment: shouldn't be the product name part of the products?

Comment: For me it's hard to imagine an entity called "cost". This looks like a company database. There is the list of suppliers the company deals with. There is the list of products the company sells. The products are bought from the suppliers. There is the list of employees that work for the company. And then there is the list of costs? What is a cost exactly? Why is one cost related to multiple suppliers and employees? This is an m:n relation between employee und supplier and I don't understand what this relation is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions about what you're asking here, based on what you show in your diagram, but if you can always calculate "Total Cost" using the values stored in "Total Cash Purchases" and "Total Salary Paid", then there's no need to keep "Total Cost" as a separate attribute.